# Ads feedback incomplete. (Suggestion)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, advertising

Today, looking for something an Ad appeared. It is for some interesting conference about [Accelerated computing](http://www.gputechconf.com/page/gtc-compute.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=gtc2013reg)... but it was in **California**.

As I am living in **London** I am not interested. My suggestions are:

- Any ad about something located as a conference, exhibition or so far should appear only where I am living.
- When I gave a thumbs down I had to choose uninterested. For real I was interested.. but for any in London. Maybe adding a new option in thumbs down like "not close to me"?

Comment: "Geographically inappropriate?"

Comment: Advertisers may want to target London peoples depending on the message. Not close to me is a good suggestion.

Comment: Maybe you are right 0A0D sometimes. I don't think this was the case. 
Maybe the solution can be that I can multiple locations in my profile in case I am the kind of person that lives between California and London so I am interested in both locations..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LinkedIn has a contact response for job recruiters something to the effect of **"Request was appropriate, but not at this time"** (I don't have any outstanding requests to verify the exact words).  Its implication is that the message was correctly targeted by interests, but just not needed right now.

If something like this was added to the advertising voting, it should convey both concepts - that you *are* interested (i.e. the ad content was well-targeted), but this is not geographically feasible for you.

So I would suggest:

- **Interesting, but geographically inappropriate**

However, the sidebar ad space is a little too cramped for something that wordy.  Perhaps the much less eloquent:

- **Interesting, too far away**

**Edit**:  Perhaps an even more generic approach would remove the geographic component and replace it with a non-specific *"no thanks on this one"*.  The implication is then that the ad was correctly targeted, and other ads similar to this one would welcome, but you would rather not be seeing this *particular* one any longer.

- **Interesting, but no thanks**

Comment: I have been > 125 on Stack Overflow, Superuser, and Serverfault so long I can hardly remember what the in-page wide ad banners are like.  I assume the voting is available on those as well?